# Eiffel library: JSON_OBJECT.item and common method to get content

Tags: json, eiffel

If I want to have the content value as string of a JSON_OBJECT.item ("key") without having to

```
some_json_value_as_string: STRING
    do
        if attached {JSON_STRING} l_json_o as l_s then
            Result := l_s.unescaped_string_8
        elseif attached {JSON_NUMBER} l_json_o as l_n then
            Result := l_n.item.out
        else
            check
                you_forgot_to_treat_a_case: False
            end
        end
    end
```

for a json object like

```
{
|       |       "datasource_name": "DODBC",
|       |       "datasource_username": "dev_db_usr",
|       |       "datasource_password": "somePassword",
|       |       "ewf_listening_port": 9997,
|       |       "log_file_path": "/var/log/ewf_app.log",
|       |       "default_selected_company": 1,
|       |       "default_selected_branch": 1,
|       |       "default_selected_consumption_sector": 1,
|       |       "default_selected_measuring_point": 1,
|       |       "default_selected_charge_unit": -1
|       }
```

the `{JSON_VALUE}.representation` with io.putstring is:

```
datasource_username=dev_db_usr
```

and not the **value only!!!**

is there a way to do that? I didn't find intuitive the different methods of JSON_VALUE: values as the `out` method gives the class and pointer address, which is really far from a string representation of the associated json object for me...

Answer (score 0):

The feature `{JSON_VALUE}.representation` is the string representation of the Current JSON value.

Ok, but if you have `jo: JSON_OBJECT` and then suppose you have  `datasource_username_key: STRING = "datasource_username"`

You can do

  `if attached jo.item (datasource_username_key) as l_value then
         print (l_value.representation)
  end`

Comment: in any case, "representation" returns the JSON representation .. so for a string, it will be  `"datasource_username"` and for numeric it won't be `"123"` but `123` . So really not convenient to compare string.
Now for string comparison, there is the `{JSON_VALUE}.same_string (...)` function.
It could be possible to add a `{JSON_VALUE}.to_string_value: STRING_32` , for JSON_STRING , it is obvious what it should return. For JSON_NUMERIC ... obvious for INTEGER, for REAL ... not that obvious. For JSON_BOOLEAN, _NULL ok. For JSON_ARRAY and JSON_OBJECT, not sure. Any suggestion?